# Change the display value of a GridColumn

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a column in my application that is filled with Object like this one :

```
EmplPoco{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I launch the application, it displays in the cell for the column for each row of my grid :

```
MyAppli.DataModel.EmplPoco
```

How can I change this behaviour and see the value of the property name of the object?

**EDIT**

The type of my column is

```
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn
```

The dev express version is *12.1*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try do an Override of the .ToString function in the EmplPoco class or you could also use the CustomColumnDisplayText Event of the GridView.

**Option 1:**

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Name;
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
private void grdview_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    try {
        if (e.Column.Name == MyColumn.Name && e.RowHandle >= 0) {
            e.DisplayText = ((EmplPoco)e.Value).Name;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Handle exception here
    }
}
```

**Option 3:**

```
private void grdviewAllocations_CustomUnboundColumnData(System.Object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
    try {
        if (e.Column.Name == MyColumn.Name && e.RowHandle >= 0) {
            e.Value = ((MyObject)e.Row).EmplPoco.Name;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Handle exception here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try option 3 that I added to the answer above then, create a new column and make sure it is set an an unbound column of type 'string' and then use the CustomUnboundColumnData event of the gridview.

Answer (score -1):

Change the DisplayMember property: as

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RowData.Row.Name}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer but I don't have any `DisplayMemberBinding` on my object (type `DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn`).

Comment: You should create a property descriptor and type converter classes for your data and implement the ITypedList interface for the list object. I thought you were using the extended toolkit

Comment: You guys are talking different "languages" WinForms vs. WPF ;)